# Google Vision API text detection strange behaviour - Javascript

Tags: javascript, ocr, google-vision

Recently something about the Google Vision API changed. I am using it to recognize text on receipts. All good until now. Suddenly, the API started to respond differently to my requests.

I sent the same picture to the API today, and I got a different response (from the past). I ensured nothing was changed in my code, so this is not the culprit.

Another strange thing is that, when I upload the image to https://cloud.google.com/vision/ in the response, under textAnnotations, I get an array of 183 entries. However when I post from my app I get an array of 113 entries. Below you can see my code.

```
function googleScan(imageData) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var url = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<myAPIKey>";
    var payload = {
        requests: {
            image: {
                content: imageData.split(',')[1]
            },
            features: [{
                type: 'TEXT_DETECTION',
                maxResults:50
            }]
        }
    };
    $http.post(url, payload, { headers: { "NoAuthToken": true } }).then(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(parseAnalyzedResult(response.data.responses[0].textAnnotations));
        console.log(response);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
```

I am wondering if somehow my free subscription got altered and that's why I receive a different response. Is that even possible? Has anyone stumbled upon this kind of issue before?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. For me, (I don't know why, but...) changing from TEXT_DETECTION to DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION solved the issue. Now the results received from the API are the same seen when I upload the image on Google Vision page.

Comment: I tried this however for me they are not the same results. Something must have changed in the API because else I cannot explain this inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks man DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION worked perfectly for me since i am dealing with real documents ! This is clearly mentioned here : https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I copied the JSON request from this drag&drop page and my result is still different with API and their demo page, the only difference is I use imageUri to send my file and google use their local storage (content param)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

The Google Cloud Vision API says that the "OCR automaticly detects latin charatecrs, **but** sometimes it can fail" or have a strange behavior. The API also says that you can add a parameter to **help** the ocr to detect better the text, giving a ***context to the image***.

You have to add the following code to the request.

```
"imageContext": {
        "languageHints": [
          "en"
        ]
 }
```

The result should look like this:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
            content: imageData.split(',')[1]
      },
      "features": [{
            type: 'TEXT_DETECTION',
            maxResults:50
        }],
      "imageContext": {
        "languageHints": [
          "en"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that language Hints its an array, so you can add more languages, to give the OCR, precisely, a hint.

You can read more:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#imagecontext

This helped me to don't get strange characters.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my case. Definetly something changed on google's side without giving any notice, Thank you for your input !

Comment: I found this answer when looking just for an example of the syntax of languageHints, many thanks. As an aside, specifically for French language, Google is far inferior to the Microsoft OCR API, it doesn't recognise apostrophes such as in l'eau, a major drawback when these appear all over the place in French.