# google-cloud-vision API gives fewer results

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I was using ruby client of Google Cloud Vision, to extract the vehicle information on Automobile Original Titles.

Observations:

When I used the client API, i was getting 171 words.

But, when I used the google's API demo here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/, I got 459 words. It has much of the information I was looking for.

Can anyone please explain, how to get the most out of the API ?

Comment: I just found a related question on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740363/google-vision-api-text-detection-strange-behaviour-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question, 
thanks to @marlon-giona.
I was referring to the post: [Google Vision API text detection strange behaviour - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740363/google-vision-api-text-detection-strange-behaviour-javascript)

When I used the `image.document` to extract dense text, I got the exact words I was looking for