# Differences between Google Cloud Vision OCR in browser demo and via python

Tags: python, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am fairly new to the Google Cloud Vision API so my apologies if there is an obvious answer to this. I am noticing that for some images I am getting different OCR results between the Google Cloud Vision API Drag and Drop (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) and from local image detection in python.

My code is as follows

```
import io
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = "./test0004a.jpg"

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

response = client.text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations

print('Texts:')
for text in texts:
#    print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description.encode('utf-8')))
    print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description.encode('ascii','ignore')))

    vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

    print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))
```

A sample image that highlights this is attached [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIrYw.jpg)

The python code above doesn't return anything, but in the browser using drag and drop it correctly identifies "2340" as the text. 
Shouldn't both python and the browser return the same result?. And if not, why not?, Do I need to include additional parameters in the code?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using `TEXT_DETECTION` instead of `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`, which is the feature being used in the [Drag and Drop example page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) that you shared.

By changing the method (to [`document_text_detection()`](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vision/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.document_text_detection)), you should obtain the desired results (I have tested it with your code, and it did work):

```
# Using TEXT_DETECTION
response = client.text_detection(image=image)

# Using DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION
response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
```

Although both methods can be used for OCR, as presented in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr), `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` is optimized for dense text and documents. The image you shared is not a really high-quality one, and the text is not clear, therefore it may be that for this type of images, `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` offers a better performance than `TEXT_DETECTION`.

See some other examples where `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` worked better than `TEXT_DETECTION`. In any case, please note that it might not always be the situation, and `TEXT_DETECTION` may still have better results under certain conditions:

- [Getting Different Data on using Demo and Actual API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110130990)
- [Google Vision API text detection strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740363/google-vision-api-text-detection-strange-behaviour-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. Using DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION now matches the drag and drop responses, so this is consistent. However, I am noticing that while DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION gives more responses with data (i.e. fewer cases with no result at all) it now seems to get a few wrong (whereas TEXT_DETECTION gets the correct result).

Comment: As I explained in the answer to your post, these two methods use different approaches, so depending on your use case and your images, you should use one or the other. `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` is designed to work better with dense texts and documents but there are really no other indicators that will let you decide for one or the other.